# (Has-A vs. Is-A) How to layout my program architecture? (JAVA)

Tags: java, aggregation, extends

I have three components:

- Interface: `Category`
- Parent Class: `MainCategory`
- Child Class: `SubCategory`

I know that:

1. `MainCategory` **IS-A** `Category`
2. `MainCategory` **Has-A** `SubCategory`
3. `SubCategory` **IS-A** `Category`

However, when I am trying to structure them in my code using `extends` and `implements` I am a little bit confused.  Here is what I have so far, please let me know if that makes sense or if it should be done in some other way?  Thanks.

```
public interface Category{}
```

---

```
public class MainCategory implements Category{}
```

---

```
public class SubCategory extends MainCategory implements Category {}
```

I want to know if I am thinking about it the right way.  Also each `MainCategory` is going to contain more than one `subCategory`, so is it right to use `extends` or does that not imply aggregation?  Thank you.

Comment: Note that `SubCategory` already  implements `Category` through `MainCategory`, no need to add the `implements Category` part .

Comment: Other than the extraneous `implements Category` on the `SubCategory` class, this looks OK to me.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful notes.

Comment: You said "`MainCategory` is going to contain ...". If `SubCategory` extends `MainCategory`, then `SubCategory` also will contain more than one `SubCategory`. I get the feeling you don't really mean for that to happen. ?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom Well, a `mainCategory` may contain more than one `subCategory`, that's what I am trying to do.  Having said that, does `extends` still make sense?

Comment: Nope. `extends` means _IS-A_, not _HAS-A_.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom  After reading extensively on the topic I now fully understand what you meant when you said _"If a `subCategory` extends `MainCategory`, then `SubCategory` may contain more than one `SubCategory`._  Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Glad it's sinking in. This stuff isn't easy to pick up all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you mention:

1. MainCategory IS-A Category
2. MainCategory Has-A SubCategory
3. SubCategory IS-A Category

`SubCategory` should *not* inherit from `MainCategory`.  It should simply implement `Category` interface.  If you have a lot of code in common between `SubCategory` and `MainCategory` as I would suspect that you would, then may I suggest an alternative layout:

```
class Category {
    private List<SubCategory> children = new ArrayList<SubCategory>();

    public List<SubCategory> getSubCategories() {
        return children;
    }

    public void addSubCategory(SubCategory child) {
        child.setParent(this);
        children.add(child);
    }

    public Category getParent() {
        return null;
    }
}

class SubCategory extends Category {
    private Category parent = null;

    public Category getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Category parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

*Any* `Category` may have `SubCategory`'s but only `SubCategory`'s can have a parent.  Notice that `Category` is *not* an abstract class.  My idea is that `Category` can be instantiated directly.  It would be the root category and the basis for most logic in your `SubCategory` class.  The `SubCategory` can override any behavior particular to a `SubCategory`.  If you find that you're having to overload a lot of behavior in `SubCategory`, then make `Category` an abstract class and create a `MainCategory` instead, but I suspect that won't be your case.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Neil that is very helpful indeed and thank you very much.  It makes sense.

Comment: @moe I'm glad to hear it.  :)

Answer (score 2):

`MainCategory Has-A SubCategory` means a SubCategory object is defined inside MainCategory as below. This is not actually acheived by extending.

```
public class MainCategory implements Category{
      public SubCategory subcat = new SubCategory();
}

public class SubCategory implements Category{
}
```

`SubCategory IS-A Category` is already done with the step `MainCategory IS-A Category` because SubCategory is a sub class of MainCategory

Comment: Yes @ErickG.Hagstrom, In my example also, I created a instance of `SubCategory` as a member of `MainCategory`. So is the `MainCategory Has-A SubCategory` relationship is achieved.

Comment: Oh, I totally misread this. I guess it was too early in the morning. My bad. I just edited so I could change my vote. Feel free to revert the edit if you like.

Answer (score 1):

To get these:

```
MainCategory IS-A Category
MainCategory Has-A SubCategory
SubCategory IS-A Category
```

You want these:

```
// MC is a category and has a SC
public class MainCategory implements Category{
    // One or more SCs
    SubCategory sc1, sc2;
    ArrayList<SubCategory> scList;
    SubCategory [] scArray;
}

// SC is a category
public class SubCategory implements Category {}
```

You only extend `SubCategory` to `MainCategory` if:

```
SubCategory IS-A MainCategory
```

Comment: @BlueMoon93 Thank you.